# How to create a hyperlink in a variable in python which should reflect in discord

Tags: python, discord, hyperlink

I have a variable
Google = "For more information please visit [Google]
(https://www.google.com)"

where it is not creating hyperlink in discord
How do that

I want to have a hyperlink that should work in Discord

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.description = "For more information please visit [Google] (https://www.google.com)"
```